# Calculate sum of GCD's of 1 to N numbers with N

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a value N which varies from

> 1 <= N <= 10^6

Say:

> N = 5

I want to calculate **sum**

where :

> sum = gcd(1,5) + gcd(2,5) + gcd(3,5) + gcd(4,5) + gcd(5,5)

I achieved this by writing these two functions :

```
function calculateSum($N){
    $gcdSum = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $N; $i++){
        $gcdSum += gcd($N,$i);
    }
    return $gcdSum;
}

function gcd($a, $b){
    if($b == 0) {
        return $a;
    }
    else {
        return gcd($b, $a % $b);
    }
}
```

I want to know what other better and faster ways of doing this exist and how to achieve them.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you can start from N to 1 and using memorization

Comment: @CSK Any example on how this memorization works. it would be great help.

Comment: i guess you can find all divisors of N and then divide 1-N by divisors.... if mod == 0 mean GCD

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568231/sum-of-greatest-common-divisor-of-all-numbers-till-n-with-n